# How do i parse the given json format?

Tags: java, json

`{
      installedApplications {
        id: 16
        aid: 4539749
        appName: "A31-RT1"
        description: "A31-RT1"
        applicationLogoUrl: "/applications/16/applicationlogo"
        applicationCompanyOrBusinessLogoUrl: "/applications/16/companyorbusinesslogo"
        appProviderName: ""
        appProviderPersoEndpointUrl: ""
        appProviderDeleteEndpointUrl: ""
        androidAppPackageName: "N"
        isUnpublished: false
        isInstallationAllowed: true
        isApprovedForSharedSlot: false
        lastUpdatedDate: -1
        contactEmail: "pallavi.shanmukhaiah@nxp.com"
        linkToTermsAndConditions: ""
        linkToApplicationWebsite: ""
        applicationSize: 288
        businessSegment: "Infrastructure"
        supportedCardLogoUris: "/applications/3/supportedcards/53/cardlogo"
        21: 0
      }`
 i tried many times but i am not able to excess the id and aid ?
please help me to write an code to parse this json format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: What you posted is not valid JSON. There should be a `:` after `installedApplications` and the fields should be separated by commas, not newlines.

Comment: This is the only response i'm getting , i cannot change the format of the JSON. @Jesper

Comment: If this is really exactly what you are getting, then it's not JSON, but something that just superficially looks like JSON. You won't be able to parse this with a JSON parser - you'll have to write a parser for it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
```

You have the obj with you so go ahead like:

```
int id = (int) obj.getJSONObject("installedApplications").get("id");
int aid = (int) obj.getJSONObject("installedApplications").get("aid");
```

I hope this helps.